# d3 js - How to draw a slopped line with given x domain range and y domain values as max & 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

I am trying to a plot a slopped line using d3 js.

for example:

x-axis domain values are ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

y-axis scale, maximum value is 70 and minimum value is 0.

How to form the data structure?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I forgot to add the question at the last line, edited my question now. Actually after analysing a bit I came up with proper data structure to draw the line

Comment: I did not mean that way.. I am new to use stack overflow so sometimes failing to form a proper question. I am also new to charts failing to think to form proper data sometimes.

Comment: Well, I see you found yourself a solution...

Comment: Yeah... I was trying since yesterday, I thought of keeping the question with old code but I was rethinking about the data and then I found the way. Yesterday you have given me nice hacky solution to move the x-axis ticks, in that fiddle I had already implemented horizontal lines. But I was failed to do a slopped line to represent ideal behaviour

Answer (score -1):

Actually I had to draw an ideal line from maximum to minimum on y-axis with varying x-axis domain values. 
So I found a way to do that by mapping the original data with wide range of data to new data with two points.

[`Working demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/cjithender/24g8k23g/4/)